# cannot call template memeber function from template member function

Tags: c++, templates, methods

I successfully implemented a Set template as an AVL balanced binary search tree. Now I am trying to make the code shorter and more readable. When merging fix_imbalance_left and fix_imbalance_right into fix_imbalance templated with left_or_right, I ran into problems. I started over step by step, and now I am at fix_imbalance(left_or_right,node) and get the following error:

```
adts/implementations/set.cpp:224:3: error: no matching function for call to ‘Set<int>::rotate(Set<int>::nodeT*&)’
adts/implementations/set.cpp:224:3: note: candidate is:
adts/implementations/set.cpp:70:39: note: template<Set<int>::directionT DIRECTION> void Set::rotate(Set<ElemT>::nodeT*&) [with Set<ElemT>::directionT DIRECTION = L, ElemT = int]
```

Note that the rotate(node) template is implemented and merged (left+right into template) and was successfull before with the separate fix_imbalance's.
I already tried: 'this->' and specifying both template arguents after fucntionname in separate <>'s, but none of those helped.

Could you please point out what am I doing wrong ?

more code:

```
enum directionT { LEFT=0, RIGHT=1 }; // inside class definition

template <directionT DIRECTION> void rotate(nodeT * & t); // line 70, inside class def

template <typename ElemT>
bool Set<ElemT>::fix_imbalance(directionT direction, nodeT * & node)
{
    directionT R = (direction==LEFT) ? RIGHT : LEFT;
    ...
    rotate<R>(node); // line 224
    ...
}

// this below worked before,
// when fix_imbalance_left and fix_imbalance_right were separate
// there I called rotate<LEFT>(node); and rotate<RIGHT>(node); and it worked
template <typename ElemT>
template <typename Set<ElemT>::directionT L>
void Set<ElemT>::rotate(nodeT * & t)
{ ... }
```

Sorry I did not post this earlier.

Comment: I think we'll need to see the code that's causing the error, lines 70 and 224 and a bit of context.

Comment: You're probably missing a `typename`.

Comment: @Charles or `template`, since he's calling a template from a template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to instantiate a template from a variable. Try instead:

```
template <typename ElemT>
bool Set<ElemT>::fix_imbalance(directionT direction, nodeT * & node)
{
    directionT R = (direction==LEFT) ? RIGHT : LEFT;
    ...
    if (R==LEFT)
         rotate<LEFT>(node); // line 224
    else
         rotate<RIGHT>(node);
    ...
}
```

Comment: So the compiler isn't "smart" enough to do what is obvious? I was trying to use templates to get rid of almost duplicate functions and to make the code shorter,etc. But apparently templates are not meant to be used for that, since the code gets longer and more complicated in so many ways, that I rather have duplicate versions. "(R==LEFT) ? rotate<LEFT>(node) : rotate<RIGHT>(node)" is equivalent to what you suggested? Thanks by the way.

Comment: So variables are never evaluated at compile time ? Even when there are just 2 cases, and its obvious ?

Comment: If you wanted it too work the way you suggest you have to pass `directionT` as an argument to the rotate function. You can evaluate variables at compile time but you have to use very specific techniques see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming

Comment: @user1358 the compiler has to create a single function body for `fix_imbalance` to which you provide two inputs - `direction` and `node`. If you always know direction at compile time, you could make it into a template parameter to `fix_imbalance`.

Comment: @Fiktik: Thats what I did originally and thats where I met my error message first. The function parameter version was just a step back to find the source of the error. Now I do not know how to make it work without that error message because of "template instantiation from variable" nor that its ugly/verbose/unreadable like template meaprogramming. I guess you cannot do all that at once in in C++. Can you ?